# chunk_xxx.mfs more and more ，How to setting biggest number?

Tags: moosefs

In mfshdd.cfg file I setting path is /data/mfs
Using MFS for several year,I found the /data/mfs more and more biger.I don't know How to setting mfsXXX.cfg to auto delete ?Anyone know please help me

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't delete any files from directories (typically HDDs mountpoints), which are listed in `/etc/mfs/mfshdd.cfg`, because the files which are inside directories presented by you on the screenshot above (chunks, named as you mention `chunk_xxx.mfs`) contain your data!

If you want MooseFS to move chunks from specific HDD to any other HDDs, just put an asterisk (`*`) before the path to this HDD in `/etc/mfs/mfshdd.cfg` - it will move chunks to other HDDs, typically on other Chunkservers. If you want to move chunks to other HDDs on the same machine, put "lower than" sign (`<`) before the path to specific HDD in `/etc/mfs/mfshdd.cfg`, e.g.:

```
*/data/mfs
```

or:

```
</data/mfs
```

For more information, refer to `man mfshdd.cfg` and read the comments in `/etc/mfs/mfshdd.cfg.dist` (MooseFS 2.0) or `/etc/mfs/mfshdd.cfg.sample` (MooseFS 3.0).